# Why do writers use "said" instead of "asked" when someone asks a question?

Tags: dialogue, language

I often see writers use "said" instead of "asked" when their character asks a question.

e.g. From *The Hobbit*:

> “Where else should I be?” said the wizard

Is it a mistake that hasn't been caught by the editor, or is it acceptable to ask a question with "said"?

Comment: Related: [Alternatives to “he said” in dialog](http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/6911/26) and [I'm getting tired of “he said” “she said” in dialogue; how do I get around it?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/3161/26) Also, on English Language & Usage: [Is there a name for the words used after dialogue?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/105043/161)

Comment: It would be much better as:  *So like the wizard went, "Where else should I be?"*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's stylistic. You can use either. "Said" isn't wrong.

Some writers feel very strongly about "bookisms," which is using words instead of "said" which tend to be more elaborate and give some action to speaking. (*hissed, crooned, muttered, sighed, barked, laughed, snarled, grumbled*) Personally I'm fine with them if they are used appropriately and judiciously, but your mileage may vary.

"Asked" isn't really a bookism, but it is a touch redundant (you pretty much only ask a question).

(Plus look, we're talking Tolkien, and linguistics professors can do whatever the hell they like with languages.)

Answer (score 10):

### Because it's less intrusive.

Anything you speak is something you say; "asking" is merely a more specific description of how the thing is being said.

Some writing wisdom holds that using "said" is lazy/boring, but always using specific descriptors like "asked" when the questioning tone is obvious from context can be equally disruptive to the flow of reading. "Said" doesn't call attention to itself like "asked" does, and lets the reader continue the conversation with minimal interruption. Overuse of more descriptive verbs may lead to [Tom Swifties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Swifty).

Answer (score 5):

In this case he wasn't expecting an answer. Gandalf, that is.

Comment: You're answering the example, not the question. But... this is technically correct.

Comment: The other answers have merit, although they rub my sense of proper wrong, I only mismatch like that when I want to draw attention.

Comment: I think this IS answering the question, at least partially.  When someone asks a *rhetorical* question, they're not really asking.  They are saying.  "Can I kiss you?" asked Susie.  "Is the Pope Catholic?" said John.

Comment: You may have answered the example, but it illustrate very well the
fact that the choice of words always adds meaning to the sentence, it
always nuances the text. However, making the nuances too obvious may
be a style error: some must be left to the reader's interpretation as
he co-creates the story.

Answer (score 1):

Said is always appropriate as a dialogue tag, whether it's a question or a statement, and asked is fine as well when a character is asking a question.

Side note: Said and asked are the ONLY dialogue tags you should ever use. Grunted, hissed, wept, replied, cried, etc, are not acceptable and will get you a manuscript full of red marks from your editor if you ever try to publish. These colorful tags are actually considered lazy writing, as the emotion you are trying to convey in the dialogue should be present in the line itself or in the description.

When I published my first novel, I spent way too much time correcting these colorful dialogue tags and changing them to said and asked. Live and learn. Unfortunately, students in schools are told the exact opposite. I've even seen teachers send home a list of tags to use instead of said.